# Bootstrap sidebar links are not contracting & collapsing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap sidebar](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript).

Its only two levels sidebar nav on the website. I have added two more levels, now its four level sidebar. I am receiving a random issue
that some time when I click on second nav of same level it doesn't open nor other nav collapse, until and unless I scroll down. Then it starting working back again.

Like in the below ScreenShot. By clicking on 'Alerts' it should open and accessing should collapse but its not. But on scrolling it working fine.

[image]

I have added the code. Please do let me know if i can add anything more.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".p8-sidebar" onLoad="fixNavbarIssue()">
<div class="p8-sidebar hidden-print hidden-sm hidden-xs bs-docs-sidebar hidden-print affix" role="complementary">          
            <ul class="nav p8-sidenav nav-stacked">                                   
              <li class="active">              
                <a href="#accessing-console">Console</a>                
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class=""><a href="#heading-login">Login</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#heading-alerts-console">Understanding Console</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#heading-connected-users">Connected Users</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#heading-connected-consoles">Connected Consoles</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#heading-logout">Logout</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

              </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="#heading-alerts">Alerts</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="">
                    <a href="#headings-new-alert">Creating a New Alert</a>                  
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#sub-heading-basic-information">Basic Information</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#sub-heading-send-to">Send To</a>    
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#sub-heading-event-name">Event Name</a>    
                      </li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sub-heading-short-message">Short Message</a>    
                      </li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sub-heading-long-message">Long Message</a>    
                      </li>
                      <li class="">
                        <a href="#sub-heading-require-acknowledgement">Require Acknowledgement</a>    
                      </li>
                    </ul>
```

Bootstrap `css/js` are unchanged.

Comment: Please provide your code, or bootply, it's not 100% the same, else it will worked...

Comment: Ok. i will update my question with code... or will add a fiddle if feasible...

Comment: I have added the HTML code...

Comment: You just send the nav html of the